# why does my carbuncle always use Gust and not Gouge?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

My Carbuncle loses agro all the time but never seems to use Gouge instead.

Comment: What level are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have your two Carbuncles mixed up. Gust is the "auto-attack" spell of the Emerald Carbuncle, summoned with the spell *Summon*. Gouge is the "auto-attack" spell of the Topaz Carbuncle, summoned with the spell *Summon II*. They function differently, and serve different roles - Emerald Carbuncle is best suited for group activities (like dungeons, FATEs, etc.), whereas Topaz Carbuncle is best suited for soloing (since all of his abilites have increased enmity generation).

Note that *Summon II* and the Topaz Carbuncle aren't earned until level 15 upon completion of the quest Topaz Teachings, available in the Arcanist's Guild in Limsa Lominsa.

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a shared cool down and the skills show on my pet list other than poor UX design?

Comment: @ton.yeung They "share a cooldown" because they occupy the same location on the pet bar (at least as far as the keyboard mode one works - I have never played XIV with a controller so I can't speak to that). They're both in your pet spellbook because, for example, as a Scholar, I want both Eos and Selene's Embrace spells keybound (they're not the same). You can keybind spells of pets that aren't active at current.

Comment: I see, is there a reason why I have the Topaz Carbuncle skills even though I don't have the Topaz Carbuncle, yet?

Comment: Because eventually you will, and you may wish to keybind them in advance. Much for the same reason you have the later abilities for your class listed, even though you're not their level yet.